# ¿Cómo sustituyo por NA un valor de una matriz que aparece en un vector externo?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo una matriz en la que hay un valor por celda. Por otro lado, tengo un vector similar.

Me gustaría que, para cada valor de la matriz, si dicho valor aparece en alguna posición del vector, se sustituya dicho valor de la matriz por NA. Así, todos los valores de la matriz que aparecen en el vector quedarían como NA.

Ej: Digamos que tengo la siguiente matriz

| Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 | Var 4 | Var 5 | Var 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | e | g | i | a |
| b | d | f | h | j | l |

Y el siguiente vector

| Vector_delete |
| --- |
| c |
| h |
| j |
| a |

Necesito este resultado:

| Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 | Var 4 | Var 5 | Var 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | e | g | i | NA |
| b | d | f | NA | NA | l |

Gracias.

Comment: seria ideal colocar ejemplo de lo que has intentado hacer

Comment: Editado, gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más simple, dado que los datos parecieran ser todos del mismo tipo, sería trabajarlos como una matriz:

```
df_m <- as.matrix(df)
df_m[df_m %in% valores] <- NA
df_m
```

En este caso, `df_m %in% valores` retorna una matriz lógica que indica las celdas a reemplazar. Por últimos si quieres mantener la condición de `data.frame` puedes convertir la matriz: `as.data.frame(df_m)`

Comment: Solucionado Patricio, gracias :-)